# What is the most straightforward way to install Glib (not GLib) ? (Windows OS/ for python coding)

Tags: python, windows-10, gtk, glib

I am going through the book "Python An introduction to programming" and the author uses the Glib library. He mentions a "static Glib" and a "dynamic Glib" which seems to be two different libraries.

I went online and found the Gnome website (https://developer.gnome.org/glib/) but this seems to be only manuals. The only place I found something related to its installation is on the GTK+ website (https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php) where it seems to be included in the installation package.

I want to use Glib in python and I'm using Windows 10.

Is GTK+ install the most straightforward way to install Glib? Does that Glib include both the "dynamic" and "static" version of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the wrong track. The GLib in GTK+ is spelled GLib (capital G, capital L). A quick web search on your book shows the [web page of the author](https://sites.google.com/site/pythonparker/) talks about:

> This book introduces a multimedia code module Glib that can assist the programmer with graphics, animation, sound, interaction, and video. The basic library, static Glib (tkinter), needs nothing but a standard 3.4 or better installation of Python. It uses tkinter as a basis, which is distributed with the language.

So the name is poorly chosen, but he says [his Glib](http://www.minkhollow.ca/parker/Glib/) is a layer over Tkinter, which is a toolkit different from GTK. The GLIB (sic) link on top of that page send you to a page where you can download that module. Clicking on download arrow on the the right will download that simple glib.py file.

This may be explained at the beginning of the book, so please, read carefully.
If it's not, then I'm not sure I would trust a guy to teach me things when he's not able to do [a wikipedia search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLib) to check if a name is taken when choosing a module name.

If what you really want is use GTK+, here's the [GTK+ 3 python tutorial](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (which will teach you GTK+, but won't teach you python).

Comment: I think I will have a look tomorrow but I think I was indeed confused. Let me mark your comment as answer once I have reviewed all this. Thank you!

Comment: Indeed, I think I'll go to my next book in line. I kept having hits with Tkinter, glib, Glib, GLib, GLIB so I guess that this solves it all. Cheers